# iOS does iTunes automatically crop your icon?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, itunes

I know that iOS app icons are automatically cropped to the nice rounded shape and a reflection effect is added when installed on the device. Is this same effect also automatically done with the 512x512 image in iTunes or do I need to design it the right shape? If I do is there a template I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 512 x 512 image will be resized to the correct size wherever it is used in the store. iTunes also adds the rounded edges and the gloss and reflection as well. If you want to have a "pre-rendered" icon (meaning no gloss is added), add this as an entry to your .plist file:

```
UIPrerenderedIcon TRUE
```

There's also a series of icons *in* your application. Here's what I have set in my applications (these are also in your .plist file):

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>iPhoneAppIcon.png</string>

<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
    <string>Icon@2x.png</string>
    <string>iPhoneAppIcon.png</string>
    <string>iPadAppIcon.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small-50.png</string>
    <string>Icon-Small.png</string>
</array>
```

For reference...

- iPhoneAppIcon.png (57x57) (iOS - 1,3G,3GS,1st/2nd Gen Touch)
- Icon@2x.png (114x114 - for retina display)
- iPadAppIcon.png (72x72 - for iPad)
- Icon-Small-50.png (50x50 - for iPad spotlight search)
- Icon-Small.png (29x29 - for spotlight search)

So Apple does a lot for you in the iTunes store, but you still have to make a bunch for in your app. I usually start by creating a 512x512 and resize down from there and make adjustments in the little guys as needed.

Comment: Thanks I knew I had to have a 512x512 I just didnt know if it did the rounded edges. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The 512 icon needs to be uploaded in iTunes Connect. As for your app, you will need the following icon sizes when submitting to Apple:

```
iPad icon: 72 x 72

iPhone icon: 50 x 50, 57 x 57

Retina icon: 114 x 114
```

If you use Xcode to validate your project, it will tell you what icon sizes are required if they are missing form your project, thats my best recommendation.

Also, you should read over the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf), specifically page 12.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, iTunes does it automatically for the store, just like for the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the size 512x512, else apple will reject it.

Reflection is not nesscary. It will add automatically.

You can google around for the template. Here is one of them.
http://blog.cocoia.com/2010/iphone-ipad-icon-psd-template/

Answer (score 0):

As for the reflection on your icon, this can be removed by adding the option `Icon already includes gloss effects` in your plist, set this to `TRUE`.

I would create a 512 x 512 icon in your favorite graphics editor, then save a copy scaling down to one of the respective sizes in my first answer.

When editing your icon, you do not have to add the "reflection" effect, if you want this, then uncheck the above option.

Answer (score 0):

Just an extra note from the iOS dev website:
For iPad apps, you will need to include small icons in your binary that are 72 x 72 and 50 x 50. iPhone OS trims 1 pixel from each side of your artwork and adds a drop shadow. Be sure to take this into account as you design your icons.